# SQL command line in windows and xamp issue

Tags: sql, windows, import, xampp

I want to do an import:
this is my command:

```
mysql -u root -p axelen > C:\Users\Netlogiq\Desktop\netlogiq_axelen.sql
```

After that it ask me about the password and after that nothing happens. What am i doing wrong ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Short Question - short answer. You just have to turn your `>` to `<`:

```
mysql -u root -p axelen < C:\Users\Netlogiq\Desktop\netlogiq_axelen.sql
```

Comment: Please expalin what the OP was doing wrong and highlight the change your answer has.  It can be hard to pick out when there is only a one character difference.

Comment: Yes, please detail what your answer is trying to achieve.

Comment: Done - hope this is enough